# Appcelerator Android Facebook Login Problems

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, appcelerator

I'm trying to let app users log into my Appcelerator app via Facebook. The Facebook app is in place. The correct hashes should also be in the Facebook dev system. The iOS login works perfect. Android however, gives this error:

```
[DEBUG] :  TiFacebookModule: (KrollRuntimeThread) [7865,569655] authorize called, permissions length: 1
[DEBUG] :  TiFacebookModule: (KrollRuntimeThread) [0,569655] authorizing permission: email
[DEBUG] :  ActivityWorkerProxy: (main) [232,569887] ActivityWorkerProxy onActivityResult
[ERROR] :  TiFacebookModule: (main) [1,569888] FacebookCallback error: Login attempt failed.
[ERROR] :  E/        : UID 10070 asks for /proc/cpuinfo
[ERROR] :  E/        : Unable to open file /data/data/.appwithABI2
[ERROR] :  E/        : Unable to open file /data/data/.appwithABI2neon
[ERROR] :  E/        : UID 10070 is not in ARM UID list files
```

**tiapp.xml:**

```
## SDK: 6.0.1GA
## facebook module included (android 6.2.0)

<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <application>
            <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="myNewApp"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
            <activity android:name="com.mynewapp.android" />
            <resources>
                <string name="facebook_app_id">[actual_FB_ID#]</string>
            </resources>
        </application>
        <resources>
            <string name="facebook_app_id">[actual_FB_ID#]</string>
        </resources>
    </manifest>
    <resources>
        <string name="facebook_app_id">[actual_FB_ID#]</string>
    </resources>
</android>
```

The app_id is an actual, valid, real app ID#. I have it in multiple places just to make sure the app can see it properly.

**strings.xml:** *(COMPLETE FILE)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name" formatted="false">[Tried both the Facebook "Display Name" & the "Namespace"]</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">[actual_FB_ID#]</string>
</resources>
```

**Facebook APP / Settings:**

```
App ID: [actual_FB_ID#]
App Secret: ******
Display Name: A Display Name
Namespace: anamespace
App Domains: [EMPTY]
Privacy: [EMPTY]
Terms: [EMPTY]
Category: Health & Fitness

// ANDROID
Google Play Package Name: [see below]
Class Name: [package name above + .index]
Key Hashes: [4: 6.0.0.GA, 6.0.1.GA, 6.0.2.GA, and 6.0.3.GA] 
Amazon App Store: [EMPTY]
Single Sign On: No
```

There is no Google play package name since it's not published yet. I used the App id from tiapp.xml

**Facebook Products / Facebook Login / Settings:**

```
Client OAuth Login: Yes
Web OAuth Login: Yes
Force Web OAuth Reauthentication: No
Embedded Browser OAuth Login: No
Valid Redirects: [EMPTY]
Login From Devices: Yes
```

**Facebook Developer Settings // Sample App Settings:**

```
Entering key hashes here doesn't save. I enter the same hashes as in the android settings above, hit "Save Changes", and they just disappear.
```

**alloy.js:**

```
Alloy.Globals.Facebook = require('facebook');
var fb = require('facebook');
```

**index.js:**

```
$.index.fbProxy = fb.createActivityWorker({
    lifecycleContainer: $.index
});

fb.initialize();
fb.setLoginBehavior(fb.LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE);
fb.permissions = ['email'];
fb.addEventListener('login', doFBlogin);

function facebookButtonClick(e){
    fb.authorize();
}

function doFBlogin(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert("Success!");
    } else if (e.cancelled) {
        alert("Cancelled!");
    } else {
        alert("Error!");
    }
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of to fix this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Facebook App ID to Android Resources? What is your facebook module version? You can try different version

- https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/releases
- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. Tiapp.xml above contains the android manifest. Did I miss something? The module version is the latest one. I may have the ability to revert to a former api, but the latest is preferable. Everything 'looks' correct, but something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add a string element to the ***/platform/android/res/values/strings.xml*** file with the name attribute set to **facebook_app_id** and the node text set to your Facebook App ID.

```
<resources>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">FACEBOOK_APP_ID</string>
</resources>
```

Since Facebook module v4.0.0, for the Android platform, you need to:

> Add the Facebook Login activity to the Android manifest Add the
>
> Facebook App ID to the Android resources string.xml file Create a
>
> Facebook proxy and associate it with the currently active activity

Seems you did not complete additional android setup steps. For details please take a look on documents:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

Comment: Actually, I did have the string file as well. Forgot to include it here. Editing the original posting to add it, along with the Facebook setup.